# Laravel. Request Validation. Unique combined from few fields

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I'm wondering how can I validate unique combined from few columns?

**For example:**

```
Table PhoneBook
Field: FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Address
```

If there is in database John Smith from London then I want to give a possibility to add a record with John Smith, but not from London.

I want to unique key combined from fields: FirstName, LastName, Address.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Laravel 5.5

1. Run the command `php artisan make:rule UniqueNameAddress`. This will create a class in the app/Rules folder with the given name (`UniqueNameAddress`)
2. In the `UniqueNameAddress` class, there is a `passes` method. This is where you verify that the requested name and address are not already used by another user. You can paste and customize the code below in the `passes` method.

   ```
   $matches = PhoneBook::whereFirstName(request(first_name))
           ->whereLastName(request(last_name))
           ->whereAddress(request(address))
           ->count();

   return $matches === 0;
   ```
3. In the `messages` method of the same class, set the message that will be returned in case of error.
4. Use the customized rule as follow

   ```
   $request->validate([
       'first_name' => ['required', new UniqueNameAddress],
   ]);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It helped immensely!